# No static method fromRunnable when running tests in Firebase Test Lab

Tags: android, firebase, android-testing, firebase-test-lab, rx-java3

Recently, our project was migrated to RxJava 3 from RxJava 2. When we run our tests in Firebase Test Lab, we see the app crashing during testing:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method fromRunnable(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Lio/reactivex/rxjava3/disposables/Disposable; in class Lio/reactivex/rxjava3/disposables/Disposable; or its super classes (declaration of 'io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.Disposable' appears in /data/app/com.example.client.developer-OsNMqNiVevCOI094EihlVg==/base.apk!classes7.dex)
```

RxJava 3 contains static interface methods, as denoted [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-3.0#disposables), but the Android Gradle Plugin should be desugaring these usages and making them work on pre-Java 8 API levels. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: You can contact the FTL team directly in the #test-lab channel of the Firebase slack. https://firebase.community/

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson I have done this